# ViewController to reload tableview data

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uialertcontroller

I call a UIAlertController from a ViewController. When I press Ok in the UIAlertController will prompt another OK dialog.

Now the problem is when I clicked on the Ok button from the dialog, I able to exit the UIAlertController but what i want is exit the UIAlertController and refresh the primary ViewController.

Can any one help me out? :(

```
- (IBAction)btnAddDidPressed:(id)sender {
    AddCashValueVC *addCashValueVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"addCashValueVC"];

    alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"nav_Add_Credit", nil) message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    [alertController setValue:addCashValueVC forKey:@"contentViewController"];

    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Above is the Primary ViewController. Show how i call the UIAlertController.

```
- (IBAction)btnProceedDidPressed:(id)sender {
[self convertCashValue];
[self dismissKeyboard];
}

-convertCashValue:{
        self->alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"msg_App", nil) message:[result objectForKey:@"msg"] preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
                self->cashValueVC.update= YES;

                UIAlertAction *openAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"btn_Ok", nil) style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {

                    CashValueVC *cashVC = [[CashValueVC alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
                    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
                        [cashVC viewDidLoad];
                        [cashVC viewWillAppear:YES];
                        [cashVC.tableView reloadData];
                    }];

                }];

                [self->alertController addAction:openAction];

                [self presentViewController:self->alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Above is the another UIAlertController in UIAlertController.

Comment: on UIAlertAction completion block you can refresh your data

Comment: I can refresh my data. But the tableview in the primary viewcontroller din't update.

Comment: You need to use main thread for UI updates.

Comment: @AbdulHoqueNuri isit possible sending some data or boolean in the main thread for UI updates? I am very new to ios

Comment: Yes you can pass and reload your table view. You need to update/refresh your table view on completion of fetching all the data.

Answer (score 0):

Following code firing one OK dialog and after tapping OK, fire another one and if tapped OK - tableview updates on main thread:

```
@interface ViewController ()<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *table;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *array; //table view dataSource
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

// update button tapped
- (IBAction)action:(id)sender {
//changing table data source
    _array = @[
               @"afasfasf",
               @"afasfasf",
               @"afasfasf",
               @"afasfasf",
               @"afasfasf",
               @"afasfasf",
               @"afasfasf"
               ];


    //alert controllers
    UIAlertController *firstAlertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"First alert"
                                                                                  message:nil
                                                                           preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertController *secondAlertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Second alert"
                                                                   message:nil
                                                            preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];





    //Actions
    UIAlertAction *firstControllerOKAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                   handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
                                                       //firing second dialog
                                                       [self presentViewController:secondAlertController animated:YES completion:nil];
                                                   }];

    UIAlertAction *secondControllerOKAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                   handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

                                                       //calling on main thread table view update
                                                       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                           [self.table reloadData];
                                                       });
                                                   }];

    UIAlertAction *cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"cancel"
                                                     style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                                   handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {}];

    //adding actions to first dialog
    [firstAlertController addAction:firstControllerOKAction];
    [firstAlertController addAction:cancel];

    //adding actions to second dialog
    [secondAlertController addAction:secondControllerOKAction];
    [secondAlertController addAction:cancel];


    //firing first dialog
    [self presentViewController:firstAlertController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

//delegate and datasource methods
- (nonnull UITableViewCell *)tableView:(nonnull UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView registerClass:UITableViewCell.class forCellReuseIdentifier:@"23"];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"23"];

    cell.textLabel.text = _array[indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(nonnull UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return _array.count;
}



@end
```